# What is the 'STEP' in NPP library?

Tags: cuda, npp

I have some question about NPP library...

This is about **Step** in NPP parameters.
When I use NPP library, it makes me confused.

`nppiSub_32s_C1RSfs(d_sink, step, d_source, step, d_terminals, step, size, 0);`

that is example..
I can understand all parameters except the step.
Every NPP function needs the step.

some people use `width`...

some people use `width * sizeof(int)`.... (or `float`...)

some people make the step parameter by other library such as

`nppiMalloc_32s_C1(width, height, &step);`

I think if I use the library, that calculate step size.(but i don't know how to did...)

1. What is the step parameter?
2. How to decide step size?
3. If I use `width` or `width*sizeof(int)`, does it have an effect on the performance?

thank you for reading my question....

English is more difficult than programming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/NPP_Library.pdf) under **4.2.2.1.4**

`The source image line step is the number of bytes between successive rows in the image.`

That means that `step` is calculated as `step = (column elements) * sizeof(element datatyp)`, if there is no padding! If you uses padding, than of course the size in bytes of padded elements have to add, too.